# disable table tab in heidisql gui for some users

Tags: heidisql

Im new to heidisql and have created a new user with read only rights on one database
It shows table schema in Table tab in heidisql
Is there any way i can hide this tab for a particular user?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The screnshot is from a super old version of HeidiSQL. Is it v3.0? Current release is v9.3! You should consider to update to the latest release.

However, there is no way to hide the table tab in HeidiSQL itself. But even better: You can restrict other MySQL user accounts not to allow ALTER and/or CREATE commands. This is what the table tab does when you edit or add some column to the table. That way, users cannot even run a self written ALTER/CREATE command through a query tab.

> I [...] have created a new user with *read only rights* on one database

That should do it already. From a technical point of view there is no need to also hide the table tab, which cannot be used to change anything if the user does not have appropriate privileges to do so.